# Tengo un error al iniciar con nginx rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un error al iniciar con nginx

el puerto es 3000

version rvm 2.3.1

version rails 5.1.1

ruta del archivo

```
   administrador@administrador-Lenovo-Product:~/Escritorio/sider
```

**sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
   user www-data;
   worker_processes auto;
   pid /run/nginx.pid;

   events {
      worker_connections 768;
      # multi_accept on;
   }

   http {

       ##
       # Basic Settings
       ##

       sendfile on;
       tcp_nopush on;
       tcp_nodelay on;
       keepalive_timeout 65;
       types_hash_max_size 2048;
       # server_tokens off;

       # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
       # server_name_in_redirect off;

       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type application/octet-stream;

       ##
       # SSL Settings
       ##

       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       ##
       # Logging Settings
       ##

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       ##
       # Gzip Settings
       ##

       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";

       # gzip_vary on;
       # gzip_proxied any;
       # gzip_comp_level 6;
       # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
       # gzip_http_version 1.1;
       # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        #Phusion Passenger config
        #
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

         include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        }


        #mail {
        #   # See sample authentication script at:
        #   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
        # 
        #   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
        #   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
        #   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
        # 
        #   server {
        #       listen     localhost:110;
        #       protocol   pop3;
        #       proxy      on;
        #   }
        # 
        #   server {
        #       listen     localhost:143;
        #       protocol   imap;
        #       proxy      on;
        #   }
        #}
```

**include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;**

```
   passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
   passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;


   passenger_root /home/cig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@sider/gems/passenger-5.1.7;

   passenger_ruby /home/cig/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1@sider/ruby;
```

**sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
      ##
       # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid           understanding
      # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
      # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
      # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
      # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
      #
      # Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
      # file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
      #
      # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
      ##

      # Default server configuration
      #
      server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

      # SSL configuration
      #
      # listen 443 ssl default_server;
      # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
      #
       # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
      # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
      #
      # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
      # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
      #
      # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
      # Don't use them in a production server!
      #
      # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

       root /var/www/html;

      # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

      location / {
         # First attempt to serve request as file, then
         # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }


      # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
      #location ~ \.php$ {
      # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      #
      # # With php7.0-cgi alone:
      # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      # # With php7.0-fpm:
      # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      #}

      # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
      # concurs with nginx's one
      #
      #location ~ /\.ht {
      # deny all;
         #}
      }


    # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    #
     # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
   # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
   #
   #server {
   #    listen 80;
   #    listen [::]:80;
   #
   #    server_name example.com;
   #
   #    root /var/www/example.com;


       #    index index.html;
       #
       #    location / {
       #        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       #    }
       #}
       server {
          listen 80 default_server;
           listen [::]:00 ipv6only=on;





    server_name localhost;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/cig/Escritorio/sider/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```

sudo service nginx start

```
     Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status nginx.service**

```
    Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: @Gerry ud tiene conocimiento de esto?gracias